# Multiple InfoWindows for Google maps with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I cant seem to make infowindows work with coffeescript . My initialisation code creates a Class  with the constructor creating a Google map and then according to the needs of the user interface ,I use the methods of the class like 'addSingleMarkers' to place markers on the map if is needed. The markers work they are beig displayed on the map properly, but when I try to place infoWindows for each marker it fails. With this code once and only once on the first click of any marker an infoWindow is displayed with the correct information for the marker, if this infoWindow is closed then it cannot open again. I have red series of posts on this for javascript but just cant get it to work with coffeescript. what am I doing wrong ?

```
class window.GoogleMap
  constructor: (@canvasID   = "#google_map",
            @searchID   = "#google_map_search",
            @rectBounds = "#google_map_rect") ->
  mapOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, 23.5),
   zoom: 8,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

  @gmap = new google.maps.Map($(@canvasID)[0], mapOptions) if $(@canvasID).length 
  true



  addSingleMarkers: (data) ->

    for coordinates, text of data
      point_length = coordinates.length
      data_array =
      coordinates.substring(6,point_length).
      replace('(','').replace(')','').split(" ")
      point = new google.maps.LatLng(data_array[1],data_array[0])
      marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        position: point
        map: @gmap
        title: text)
      @bindInfoW marker, text   


  bindInfoW : (marker, contentString) ->
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", ->
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow    
      infowindow.setContent contentString
      infowindow.open @gmap, marker
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the line : `google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", ->` where it should have been `google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", =>` Also I created a seperate method call to create only one instance of InfoWindow. There is a difference between -> and => . The latter creates a temp variable var _this = this and uses it later with the infoWindow